# Why can't I see the inverse kinematics y limitation?

Tags: rigging

Beginner rigger question:

If I click "limit x" I see the x limitation by the red circle

[image]

If I click "limit z" I see the z limitation by the blue circle

[image]

Why can't I see a y limitation?   It must be something obvious...but I don't get it.

[image]

Comment: did you test it on the latest version of blender? i can confirm this, could this be a bug

Comment: Yes, I am nearly always using the newest alpha version - max 4 weeks old

Comment: in 3.0 -> the same

Comment: 2.9.3 the same, so i think, it is not a bug ;)

Comment: If the axis are not visualized in the viewport there can be a doubt about which is X and which is Z, but Y is always along the lenght of the bone, so I think that developers decided that it would be redundant to represent it.

Comment: that's sad...so i don't know where e.g. 0 degree is... :( 0r 90...or whatever

Comment: i asked on blender support chat, this is what i got: "I had noted this some time ago, AFAIK Y limit is not show but limits are working as expected. Missing UI gizmo could be a bug as well as a wanted feature" and "Bone Y axis is axis along bone length, missing green gizmo could be wanted from developers as well as this missing could be a bug. This axis rotation is related to parent bone in most case with or without IK chain enabled.

Comment: thanks for asking!